# D3, DC, CSV - How to stop scientific notation rounding numbers in js

Tags: csv, d3.js, dc.js

I'm loading multiple .csv files, which I then merge on the basis of a common ID. In some cases, the ID is an integer > 12000000000000.

Initially I was loading CSV files, but switched to DSV in the hope of fixing the problem. I'm using queue.js, so my loading code looks like this:

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.dsv("|", "text/plain"), 'portfolio2.csv')
  .defer(d3.dsv("|", "text/plain"), 'ratings2.csv')
```

Although the files have an extension of .csv, they are pipe delimited and load fine.

I think the problem is that D3 or javascript or some part of my code loads in scientific notation, and somehow it overwrites the original data with a rounded number. So where I have an ID of 12000000110858, once I load the webpage, the number changes in the CSV file to 12000000000000. There is no line of code overwriting this ID field. It's as though the act of loading the file is enough by itself.

I've tried using pipe delimited and that suffers the same problem.

Of course, my app then falls over, because it can't perform the matching. Is anyone familiar with this problem and knows of a solution?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you simply use strings instead of numbers? Besides that, for anyone being able to help you, you have to show the code that you're using for *loading the data*: for instance, if you use `d3.csv` for parsing the CSV, the numbers will **not** be loaded as numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The string loads in scientific notation. I can't match the IDs on this basis, as I'd have several rows, all with an ID of 12e13. Is there a way of loading as string without the scientific notation?

Comment: Thanks for showing your code. Something else is going on here because, as I said, `d3.dsv` loads the numbers **as strings**. I made a simple example for you, have a look at the data file (numbers), and then examine the console (strings): https://plnkr.co/edit/5GdjpfTAQJWxVmDChOni?p=preview Actually, most of D3 coders have the exact opposite problem: even if the CSV file has numbers, when loaded and parsed, D3 creates the data array converting the numbers to strings, and we have to convert them back to numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help. I agree that d3 loaders load in strings. I think the problem is that my files in Excel are saving in scientific notation, no matter what I do via Format Cells, and no matter what file type i use.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes on this, even in the first version. Harsh crowd - maybe safer not to include vague tags like javascript.

Comment: I think you'd need to format the cells as strings in Excel. Pretty sure those are too big to be treated as integers in JavaScript anyway. As @GerardoFurtado says, a snippet of your CSV data would help.